# How to reduce the video file size recorded by chrome.tabCapture() in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, mediarecorder

I am trying to record the chrome tab using chrome.tabCapture() API and MediaRecorder. I need to record the activities in the chrome tab and send the recorded video to my spring boot backend server.
In some cases, I need to record the tab for 5-10 minutes. I recorded a 20-sec video. But it has a size of 12-17 MB. I need to reduce the video size (it will be helpful for clients who have a slow network). Is there any way to reduce the file size?.

my code

```
let recData = [];
let width = 1920,
    height = 1080;

function initTabCapture() {
    recData = [];
    let captureConfig = {
        audio: false,
        video: true,
        videoConstraints: {
            mandatory: {
                minWidth: width,
                maxWidth: width,
                minHeight: height,
                maxHeight: height
            }
        }
    }
    chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureConfig, tabRecordStreamHandler)
}

function tabRecordStreamHandler(stream) {
    console.log(stream)
 var options = {
            // mimeType: 'video/mp4;codecs=H264'
            mimeType: 'video/webm\;codecs=vp8',

        };
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
    if (stream) {
       
        mediaRecorder.start();
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                recData.push(event.data);
                var blob = new Blob(recData, {
                    type: 'video/webm'
                });
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.style = 'display: none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'test.webm';
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                sendDataToServer(blob)
                
            }
        }
    }
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (request.msg == "stop-rec") {
                console.log("stoping the media recorder")
                stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
                sendResponse({ response: "Finishing recording..." });
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Well with a 1920 * 1080 resolution, you got to expect a certain data size … You could maybe specify a lower framerate in the video constraint as well.